# Salesforce Communites: Unable to see created Questions in topic detail page in sandbox after refresh from PROD

Tags: community

I am facing am issue with Salesforce Communities Using Napili Template and Winter'16 Version.
I am able to create a question by clicking on the Ask a Question button,but I am unable to see the question in the topic detail page under discussions tab.
Please check the below GIF.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Its weird for sure .I am guessing that having "/" on your Topic Name String is causing some issue .Try deleting that Topic and recreating .

Comment: Yeah. Did that just now. It happens for all the Topics not just access/setup. Cant figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Ok raise a case with Support .This seems weird .Can you query those questions in backend ?

Comment: Yup. I am able to query them as FeedItem Object Records. I did raise a case with support today. Waiting for their answer.

Comment: I see you posted in Success Community as well .Lets hope for answer from PRODUCT team on this .

Comment: Yeah. I hope they have a fix for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38257/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-karthikeya-pammi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out how to fix this. Here is how i fixed this:

Step1: Take a backup of Topic and Topic Assignments Sobject Records.

Step2: Delete all the Topics that you have on community. The associated SObject is named Topic. 
Warning: This will also delete the topic Assignments for the Topics.

Step3: Use the backup for Topic and Topic Assignments and insert those records back again.

Step4: Add the topics back to community manually from Community Management.

Thank you everyone in Community Implementation group and Mohith for helping me out on this.